# Set permissions using Temboo for Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook-fql, temboo

I am currently developing an app where I have been using temboo to search a user on Facebook. I am able to get the basic results which do not need any additional permissions.

But for fields like education history, about_me etc, I need to include additional permissions to retrieve these fields.

Could you please let me know how to add these permissions to the temboo FQLinputsets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Temboo.

I would recommend using our OAuth Helper Choreos to go through the OAuth process, and request an additional set of permissions:

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Facebook/OAuth/

In the first step of the OAuth process, you'll run the InitializeOAuth choreo. This is where you can specify the permissions you need to request by passing a comma-separated list of permissions to the "Scope" input. You'll want to pass `user_education_history,about_me` along with any other permissions you'd like to request. Here's an example of the input set:

`// Set inputs 
initializeOAuthInputs.set_AppID("YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID"); 
initializeOAuthInputs.set_Scope("user_education_history,about_me");`

Then you can complete the OAuth process by running the FinalizeOAuth choreo. This will return an access token that should have the permission you need to retrieve those fields.

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Facebook/OAuth/FinalizeOAuth/

There is a video tutorial about the OAuth Choreos here:

https://www.temboo.com/videos#oauthchoreos

Hope this helps. Let us know if you have any other questions.

Cormac

Comment: Hi Cormac, Thanks lot for the reply. Can you please let me know how to retrieve all the values of the user table? I have set the about_me permission and tried to retrieve the about_me of all the users by querying their name from the profile table, but I have been able to retreive the about_me field for only me and my friends. How do i do it for all unknown users?

Comment: I’m not sure if that’s possible. If your app gets an access token for a user (you), AND requests the correct scope, AND specifies an FQL statement of:

SELECT uid, name, about_me FROM user WHERE uid = me() 

then it will return the about_me field for you in the response.

If you’ve got an access token for yourself, and you have permission to see your friend's about_me field then you’ll just see your friends about_me info.